# HiveOS: Script (which if invoked manually via console works) doesn't start on boot when I inserted it to /home/user/initx.user.sh

Tags: shell-script, scripting, init-script

I use a mining rig running HiveOS, which I believe is based on Ubuntu.

I made a script called `amdtimings.sh` which inserts custom HBM2 timings to my GPUs via the use of a tool called [amdmemorytweak](https://github.com/Eliovp/amdmemorytweak). The script's directory is on /home/user/ and I can check it out via `dir /home/user/`
If I manually just open a console and execute `./amdtimings.sh` everything works fine.

The issue is that I want to make that script run on boot, because the PC will reboot in case of any failure (e.g. a GPU dying or overheating) but my overclock profiles won't work unless the HBM timings are set first. The overclock setup does get set up automatically by the HiveOS server, which in such case (since the script doesn't fire up on boot) just freezes the miner since it attempts to start operating the GPUs on said OC profile which can't run unless I first manually enter the timings by running the aforementioned script `./amdtimings.sh`.

I run in a GUI so X starts after each reboot, so I edited the `/home/user/initx.user.sh`  like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
           
# This script is run in terminal after X server start

# uncomment the following line if you want to see miner log after start
#tail -f /run/hive/miner.1
sleep 10
cd /home/user/
./amdtimings.sh
```

In hopes that in this way the script will start on boot, with a 10 second delay. The miner starts after 30 seconds of boot.

But for some reason, it doesn't work!

What could it be?

Comment: Is `/home/user/initx.user.sh` some sort of standard naming scheme for scripts that launch on graphical login in HiveOS? I have never seen this before, is there some documentation or something that suggests that would be automatically run? Does the script ever launch? What happens if you add `touch /tmp/somefile` to the beginning of the script? Is `/tmp/somefile` created?

Comment: @terdon I can't find any documentation on it other than everyone I asked pointing to that and that the xini.user.ph did exist before I edit it and the comment (as seen above) talks about it running after X server starts. But all good now since they updated Hive Os and now you are able to enter timings through the OC profiles which get saved and run automatically after reboot :)